# How to download the app with the CLI from the Swisscom App Cloud?

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I am trying to download my app wich is currently running in the Swisscom App Cloud.

Therefore I installed the [cf-download](https://github.com/ibmjstart/cf-download) plugin.

My command: `cf download app-name /public --verbose --omit /vendors --overwrite`

After running this command I get the following error:

> The app is running on the Diego backend, which does not support this command.

Is `cf download` thus not possible in the Swisscom App Cloud?

I've tried `cf files` as well. Same error.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with an [API call](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/213/apps/downloads_the_staged_droplet_for_an_app.html)

> Apps 
>   API Downloads the staged droplet for an App GET
>   `/v2/apps/:guid/droplet/download` When using a remote blobstore, such as
>   AWS, the response is a redirect to the actual location of the droplet.

step by step:

```
cf app $APP --guid
cf curl /v2/apps/$GUID/droplet/download > testing.gz
tar -xzvf testing.gz
```

I successfully tested it on Swisscom App Cloud.