# How to pull files from Cloud Foundry on Diego

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I would like to retrieve some application's logs. 
I found that the command `cf file` was not available anymore and the plugin `cf-download` [doesn't work on Diego Architecture](https://github.com/ibmjstart/cf-download/issues/12).
Is there a way to retrieve files from the cloud foundry by CLI other another method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download the app with the CLI from the Swisscom App Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365778/how-to-download-the-app-with-the-cli-from-the-swisscom-app-cloud)

Comment: you can also use `cf ssh` or native SSH client. See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html

Comment: The use of API didn't work for me the logs were not present. 
But in the documentation of SSH i found what i was looking for:
Application SSH Access without cf CLI. I'll refer it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [SSH without cf CLI](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#other-ssh-access)

When you are at the step 4) you can use WinSCP (for Windows) to have a graphical interface to navigate in the folders.

Comment: You cannot download logs by ssh-ing into the container. If you want logs, you should get them thru Loggregator Firehose. If you have access, you can try the cf firehose plugin for cf-cli.

Comment: By log i mean log from the application. And I was able to download them. But i'll check your solution.

Comment: You should modify your application to log to STDOUT/STDERR.  Then your logs will show up in the log stream (i.e. `cf logs`) and you won't need to go into the container to grab them.  If you have a third party app that you can't tell to log to STDOUT and you must grab the log files from the container then this is the solution (i.e. SCP/SFTP).

Answer (score 3):

A simpler albeit uncloudy / hacky solution is to use `cf ssh` to transfer via stdout.

For example, if you want to transfer all files directly under `/home/vcap/logs` you can do...

**Update:** Here's the much simpler and faster version without a for loop using only `tar`:

```
cf ssh <APP> -i <INSTANCE> -c 'tar cfz - logs/*.log' | tar xfz - -C .
```

In my case this transfers 1 GB log files in just under 20 seconds.

**Original answer:**

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p logs
for f in $( cf ssh <APP> -i <INSTANCE> -c 'ls logs/*' ); do
    cf ssh <APP> -i <INSTANCE> -c "cat $f" > $f
done
```

In my setup this took about 11 minutes to transfer 1.3GB of log files.

Using `gzip` compression brought this down to 5 minutes (replace the line in the for loop):

```
    cf ssh <APP> -i <INSTANCE> -c "cat $f | gzip -c" | gunzip > $f
```

Pretty sure this can be optimized using `tar` and getting rid of the for loop.